# Delphi thread best practices

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-7

I am implementing a synchronization method inside my application. The main steps it will perform are:

- Get XML content from a remote site
- Parse this XML using **IXMLDomDocument2**
- Update a Firebird database

The logic is quite complex, but it is working fine per se.

The problem is when I try to run it inside a separate thread. It is clear to me that I am not getting thread safety properly in my logic.

So let´s slice it

I - Get content using **TidHTTP**

Didn´t have any problems with it, should I have any concerns here?

II - For **IXMLDomDocument2** I am calling

```
CoInitializeEx(nil, 0);
```

which according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be enough to use **IXMLDomDocument2** safely. And it seems to be ok, after adding it I did not get any error when trying to use it. Any extra concern here?

III - To use Firebird safely

My problems are here. Sometimes it works, sometimes it don´t (which I guess is the main symptom of badly designed thread logic). Most of the time I get a EInterbaseError with the message "Error reading data from the connection". Other times it simply locks.

Should I have a separate connection with the database?

Comment: Definitely should not share the connection to the DB between the background and the foreground thread.

Comment: I agree with Warren.  When it comes to database, unless you know for a fact that a given DB engine (and its VCL components) is thread-safe, then don't share DB components across thread boundaries.  Give each thread its own connection and its own set of loal DB components.  Otherwise, move your DB logic to a dedicated thread that other threads can post requests to when needed.

Comment: Thank you Warren and Remy. I did create a sepparate connection and it is all right now. But I´ll keep my question and see if there´s any other concern I should have.

Answer (score 2):

Warren nailed the main problem with sharing the connection between the background and foreground thread... you have another issue and that is every call to CoInitialize needs to be paired with CoUninitialize

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: +1 for your answere. I indeed had problems for not calling CoUninitialize. But calling it didn´t solve my problem. Calling it or not results in the same unsufficient memory problem after some calls to my thread. I am sure it is the problem is with coInitialize because taking if off makes my program get no insufficient memory at all.